# Есть ли в питоне списки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли в питоне структура данных список? Для вставки и удаления элемента за O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Есть дек (collections.deque) в котором удаление и вставка сначала и с конца за O(1). `list` в питоне на массиве, тут только в конец O(1), чтоб было что-то на списке - вроде нет.